# Angular Animations for Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that needs to check for when the mouse is over a particular DOM element. Once it knows, it will add some animation to the element using the $animate service from Angular 1.2.0 RC3. In the code below, `attrs.isMouseOver` indicates that check. The issue here is that I am not sure how to check for that using attrs. Note: I do not want to use ng-mouseover unless I absolutely have to.

```
angular.module('App')
  .directive('shift', function ($animate) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.watch(attrs.isMouseOver, function (hover) {
        if (hover) {
          $animate.addClass(element, 'shift');
        } else {
          $animate.removeClass(element, 'shift');
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

Comment: elem.bind("mouseover", function(hover) ... instead of $watch.

Comment: if you `bind` you'll have to add an `$apply` as well.

Comment: It seems that it works without the $apply call.

Comment: Why would I need to use apply in this particular instance?